# ThreadSanitizer reports "data race on operator delete(void*)" when using embedded reference counter

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, reference-counting, thread-sanitizer

Please have a look at the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

class ReferenceCounted {
  public:
    ReferenceCounted() : ref_count_(1) {}

    void reserve() {
      ref_count_.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    void release() {
      if (ref_count_.fetch_sub(1, boost::memory_order_release) == 1) {
        boost::atomic_thread_fence(boost::memory_order_acquire);
        delete this;
      }
    }

  private:
    boost::atomic<int> ref_count_;
};

void* Thread1(void* x) {
  static_cast<ReferenceCounted*>(x)->release();
  return NULL;
}

void* Thread2(void* x) {
  static_cast<ReferenceCounted*>(x)->release();
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  ReferenceCounted* obj = new ReferenceCounted();
  obj->reserve(); // for Thread1
  obj->reserve(); // for Thread2
  obj->release(); // for the main()
  pthread_t t[2];
  pthread_create(&t[0], NULL, Thread1, obj);
  pthread_create(&t[1], NULL, Thread2, obj);
  pthread_join(t[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(t[1], NULL);
}
```

This is somewhat similar to the [Reference counting](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_reference_counters) example from [Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic.html).

The main differences are that the embedded `ref_count_` is initialized to `1` in the constructor (once the constructor is completed we have a single reference to the `ReferenceCounted` object) and that the code doesn't use `boost::intrusive_ptr`.

Please don't blame me for using `delete this` in the code - this is the pattern that I have in a large code base at work and there's nothing I can do about it right now.

Now this code compiled with `clang 3.5` from trunk (details below) and [ThreadSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/thread-sanitizer/) (tsan v2) results in the following output from ThreadSanitizer:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=9871)
  Write of size 1 at 0x7d040000f7f0 by thread T2:
    #0 operator delete(void*) <null>:0 (a.out+0x00000004738b)
    #1 ReferenceCounted::release() /home/A.Romanek/tmp/tsan/main.cpp:15 (a.out+0x0000000a2c06)
    #2 Thread2(void*) /home/A.Romanek/tmp/tsan/main.cpp:29 (a.out+0x0000000a2833)

  Previous atomic write of size 4 at 0x7d040000f7f0 by thread T1:
    #0 __tsan_atomic32_fetch_sub <null>:0 (a.out+0x0000000896b6)
    #1 boost::atomics::detail::base_atomic<int, int, 4u, true>::fetch_sub(int, boost::memory_order) volatile /home/A.Romanek/tmp/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:499 (a.out+0x0000000a3329)
    #2 ReferenceCounted::release() /home/A.Romanek/tmp/tsan/main.cpp:13 (a.out+0x0000000a2a71)
    #3 Thread1(void*) /home/A.Romanek/tmp/tsan/main.cpp:24 (a.out+0x0000000a27d3)

  Location is heap block of size 4 at 0x7d040000f7f0 allocated by main thread:
    #0 operator new(unsigned long) <null>:0 (a.out+0x000000046e1d)
    #1 main /home/A.Romanek/tmp/tsan/main.cpp:34 (a.out+0x0000000a286f)

  Thread T2 (tid=9874, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null>:0 (a.out+0x00000004a2d1)
    #1 main /home/A.Romanek/tmp/tsan/main.cpp:40 (a.out+0x0000000a294e)

  Thread T1 (tid=9873, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null>:0 (a.out+0x00000004a2d1)
    #1 main /home/A.Romanek/tmp/tsan/main.cpp:39 (a.out+0x0000000a2912)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race ??:0 operator delete(void*)
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
```

The strange thing is that `thread T1` does a write of size 1 to the same memory location as `thread T2` when doing atomic decrement on the reference counter.

How can the former write be explained? Is it some clean-up performed by the destructor of `ReferenceCounted` class?

It is a false positive? Or is the code wrong?

My setup is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux aromanek-laptop 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

The code is compiled like this:

```
clang++ main.cpp -I/home/A.Romanek/tmp/boost/boost_1_55_0 -pthread -fsanitize=thread -O0 -g -ggdb3 -fPIE -pie -fPIC
```

Note that on my machine the implementation of `boost::atomic<T>` resolves to `__atomic_load_n` family of functions, which [ThreadSanitizer claims to understand](https://code.google.com/p/thread-sanitizer/wiki/AtomicOperations).

UPDATE 1: the same happens when using `clang 3.4` final release.

UPDATE 2: the same problem occurs with `-std=c++11` and `<atomic>` with both [libstdc++](http://pastebin.com/56TLxpSR) and [libc++](http://pastebin.com/STPbwbTS).

Comment: I don't know what Boost means, since the C++ standard doesn't say anything about Boost, but if these were `std` atomics, then an `std::atomic_thread_fence` only synchronizes-with other atomic operations if there's a suitable intermediate access. See [atomic.fences] for details.

Comment: Try changing the fence to `ref_count_.fetch_add(0, boost::memory_order_acquire)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, indeed, changing the fence to the `fetch_add()` you proposed makes tsan quiet. However, I'm not sure if this is just a workaround for tsan or it actually fixes a race in the code.

Comment: See my comments below. The fence plays by certain rules. You can reason about the rules if you want, or you could just not use fences. Fences are a poor primitive, since it's very unusual that you wouldn't want to synchronize on some specific object.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if std::atomic reports the same issue.

Comment: @James, nothing changes with std::atomic, TSan [reports the same issue](http://pastebin.com/56TLxpSR).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a false positive.

The `thread_fence` in the `release()` method enforces all outstanding writes from `fetch_sub`-calls to *happen-before* the fence returns. Therefore, the `delete` on the next line cannot race with the previous writes from decreasing the refcount.

Quoting from the book *C++ Concurrency in Action*:

> A release operation synchronizes-with a fence with an `order` of
>   `std::memory_order_acquire` [...] if that release operation stores a
>   value that's read by an atomic operation prior to the fence on the
>   same thread as the fence.

Since decreasing the refcount is a read-modify-write operation, this should apply here.

To elaborate, the order of operations that we need to ensure is as follows:

1. Decreasing the refcount to a value > 1
2. Decreasing the refcount to 1
3. Deleting the object

`2.` and `3.` are synchronized implicitly, as they happen on the same thread. `1.` and `2.` are synchronized since they are both atomic read-modify-write operations on the same value. If these two could race the whole refcounting would be broken in the first place. So what is left is synchronizing `1.` and `3.`.

This is exactly what the fence does. The write from `1.` is a `release` operation that is, as we just discussed, synchronized with `2.`, a read on the same value. `3.`, an `acquire` fence on the same thread as `2.`, now synchronizes with the write from `1.` as guaranteed by the spec. This happens without requiring an addition `acquire` write on the object (as was suggested by @KerrekSB in the comments), which would also work, but might be potentially less efficient due to the additional write.

Bottom line: Don't play around with memory orderings. Even experts get them wrong and their impact on performance is often negligible. So unless you have proven in a profiling run that they kill your performance and you absolutely positively *have to* optimize this, just pretend they don't exist and stick with the default `memory_order_seq_cst`.

Comment: I'm suspicious of that answer. TSan is pretty good and actually runs through the C++ memory model pretty accurately. See my above comment; I think the OP's code does indeed not synchronize.

Comment: @KerrekSB See my edit. boost:atomic is [supposed to be 100% compliant with the standard atomics](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic.html). As usual with atomics, all of this is quite subtle, so I won't rule out that I interpret things wrong somewhere.

Comment: OK, thanks. See the cited standard reference - 29.8/4 sounds to me like you need, before the fence, an operation that reads the value that was being released, otherwise the fence does not synchronize with the release.

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess in that section in the Standard, `X` would be the write by the thread that performs the delete and `A` would be the write by the other thread (the one that just decreases the refcount, but does not delete). So `A` should synchronize with the fence (which is running on the same thread as `X` in this case), which is what is required to eliminate the race.

Comment: Hm... I think the write is `A`, the `ref_count_` variable is `M`, the acquire fence is `B`, and there is no `X`!

Comment: @KerrekSB Tried to elaborate a bit more. My head is spinning now, so I hope it's convincing :D

Comment: This is in fact a false positive - [it has been confirmed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/thread-sanitizer/dZ3QiQE49ns/j7rKGHg08foJ) on the thread-sanitizer discussion group.

Answer (score 2):

Just to highlight [@adam-romanek's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446561/threadsanitizer-reports-data-race-on-operator-deletevoid-when-using-embedde/49173574#comment38054424_24447301) for others who stumble upon this, at the time of writing (March 2018) [ThreadSanitizer does not support standalone memory fences](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/thread-sanitizer/dZ3QiQE49ns/j7rKGHg08foJ). This is alluded to in the [ThreadSanitizer FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual#faq) which **doesn't** explicitly mention fences are supported:

> Q: **What synchronization primitives are supported?** TSan supports pthread synchronization primitives, built-in compiler atomic operations (sync/atomic), C++  operations are supported with llvm libc++ (not very throughly [sic] tested, though).